# <a> tag in Html is Not Working in the form

Tags: html, forms

In my html form, there is a form submit (  ) button; beside that, there is also a button (    ) for back to previous page without editing any information. Just see below:

```
<form name="edit_profile_form" onsubmit="return EditProfileValidation();" method="post" action="user_info_save.php">

... 

// here text and radio fields to edit user profile info by the user.

...

    <div class="edit_profile_back_button">
        <a href="view_profile.php">
        <button class="back_to_profile"> Back to Profile Page </button>
        </a> 
    </div>

    <div class="edit_profile_save_record">
        <input type="submit" name="edit_profile_data_save" class="save_new_user_info" value="Save Record" /> 
    </div>

</form>
```

The problem is with the back button. When I click on the "Back to Profile Page" button, it submits the form to the user_info_save.php page instead of view_profile.php page.

Why the form behaviours like this ?

Kindly help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: there's no javascript/php/jquery/css here, only html

Comment: it seems that `onsubmit` and `action` attributes doesnt work together well , better leave the `onsubmit` and remove the action and then make an ajax call to your php

Comment: I removed all the irrelevant tags in an edit.

Comment: you wanna submit the form to another page with that button or its just a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default value of the button type attribute is submit.
try this :

```
<button class="back_to_profile" type="button">Back to Profile Page</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Rahele. It's working just like rocks by adding type="button" you suggested. Thanx again.